# How does a browser request a SSL certificate?

Tags: java, http, ssl

I have created a Java-based HTTP server and I want it to supply SSL certificates to browsers that access the server. I am using a java.net.ServerSocket and java.net.Socket to manage open connections.

```java
File file = new File(WEB_ROOT, parsedRequest); // generates File
int len = (int) file.length(); // determines file length
String type = getContentType(parsedRequest); // gets type
byte[] data = readFileData(file, len); // gets data
// out and dataOut are both streams constituted from OutputStreams from the java.net.Socket
out.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); // headers
out.println("Server: JavaServer : 2.1");
out.println("Date: "+new Date());
out.println("Content-type: "+type);
out.println("Content-length: "+len);
out.println();
out.flush();
dataOut.write(data, 0, len); // sending data
dataOut.flush();
```

Comment: I am guessing you created a program that serves a HTTP. What web server are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I run this program on localhost on my computer when I add features to it. You can download it (and maybe disassemble it) on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1COBAybLBfPP2CuNrvzPYRITeXZ7OzjnH/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: The SSL certificate is served by the server not the application, in most cases. If you want to make this application online, you will serve with through a web server such as ```apache``` or ```nginx``` and you would configure the  webserver to serve the certificate (once you obtain one), there are ways of using https locally depending on the frameworks you use, but it is a completely unnecessary effort in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

The browser does not "request" a certificate. If the protocol of the URL is `https://...` the browser will use HTTPS as application protocol, which is HTTP+SSL/TLS. The server must be able to handle this protocol then.  Usually HTTP and HTTPS are served on different TCP ports so the server expects HTTPS only on the port setup for HTTPS.

Comment: In the case of `https://...` would the certificate be part of the response or would the server expect to supply it on a specified port?

Comment: @VincentHarris TLS/SSL and HTTPS are different protocols in different network layers. The certificate is not transported with the https requests or responses. When you browse to ```https://...``` the browser in the background, separately asks for the cert and usually caches the cert to speed up future browsing

Comment: With `https://...` which port would the certificate be sent on?

Comment: @sinanspd: The browser does not ask for a cert. The server will provide a cert during SSL handshake but the browser does not explicitly ask for it.

Comment: @VincentHarris: the certificate would not be send "on a port". HTTPS by default uses port 443 as much is HTTP by default uses port 80. But both protocols can use other ports too, like port 1234 with a URL of `https://example.com:1234`.

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding anymore. The browser sends a request like `GET /somepage.html HTTP/1.1`. The server responds like `Content-type: text/html\nContent-length: 1234\n\n[data here]`. Where is the certificate supposed to go?

Comment: @VincentHarris: With HTTPS the browser 1. establishes a TCP connection 2. establishes a SSL/TLS session on top of this TCP connection, which includes getting and validating the certificate from the server. After the handshake everything is encrypted. 3. sends the HTTP request (´GET / ...`). With plain HTTP step#2 is omitted, i.e. no SSL/TLS and thus no certificate and also no encryption involved.